# How can I fix the node.js tools "an unexpected error occurred" issue in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-project, node.js-tools

I have a combined .Net Core / Vue app I created in VS2019.

I recently separated the app so I can run the API separate to the UI, with the UI project created in VS2022 as the project file as a .njsproj extension which is incompatible with VS2019.

When I try to load the solution now post launch in VS2022, it balks on the .njsproj project with the following error message;

[image: node.js tools for visual studio 2002 error]

I have tried updating and then repairing the VS2022 install to no avail.

I have reviewed the ActivityLog.xml file as suggested but I cannot see an error related to node.js tools, it appears to load those packages without issue.

The only recurring issue I do see is the following warnings, but they seem unrelated;

> Request for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" from Process denied because the service is only exposed RemoteExclusiveClient, LiveShareGuest.

> Request for proxy to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Internal.SettingsManager (1.0)" is declined: ServiceAudienceMismatch.

I cannot find any other error messaging that contains a clue, and even an extensive Google search has not revealed anything related. I'm a bit stumped as to what I can do now short of recreating my solution anew (which I really don't want to do - and shouldn't have to frankly).

Has anyone else encountered this issue with visual studio 2022 and node.js tools?